# Difference between super() and super (className,self) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have code snipped like :

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        return 'A'

class B(A):
    def test(self):
        return 'B->' + super(B, self).test()

print(B().test())
```

Output : B->A

If I write something like this then I'm getting the same output :

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        return 'A'

class B(A):
    def test(self):
        return 'B->' + super().test()  # change to super()


print(B().test())
```

In both cases I'm getting the same output. Then, I want to know what's the difference between this two types of calling of `super`? What are the pros and cons of using either of them?

Comment: No difference - syntax sugar.

Comment: @wim: well, yes, there very much is a difference, see [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](//stackoverflow.com/q/19608134). **Usually** it doesn't matter, but `super(B, self)` looks up `B` *late*.

Comment: Also related: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/ and [Why does Python 2's \`super\` require explicit class and self arguments?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36929210)

Comment: I'm aware, but the intricacies of the implementation are not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Python 2, only the `super(className,self)` syntax was possible. Since It was the most used version, as of [`Python 3`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super) providing no arguments will act the same.

> There are two typical use cases for super. In a class hierarchy with single inheritance, super can be used to refer to parent classes without naming them explicitly, thus making the code more maintainable